# Scrollable methods of ResultSet works even though result set type is ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I tried running this code.

```
String sql = "select name from animal order by id";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql", "root", "root");
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
 rs.absolute(0);
 rs.next();
 System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

As you can see, the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and not scrollable. Since it is not the latter, I expect that absolute() and other scrollable method, like relative(), previous(), etc., will not work. In this case, it works. Why is that? Does mysql default it to scrollable ResultSet type?

Comment: Very strange, I would expect `rs.absolute(0)` to throw an exception.  What happens if you try jumping backwards explicitly after reading a few rows?

Comment: rs.absolute(0) will point the cursor before the 1st row and will not throw an exception. I tried using previous(), relative() and other scrollable methods and it returns the expected result.